# Exact script order for Angular2 2.0.0-beta.17

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

I'm writing an **Angular2 2.0.0-beta.17** app.
I think i'm including the various polyfills and shim for angular2 in the wrong order. Unfortunatly, the doc for this version of angular is gone, replaced by the doc for rc.1.
I do not want to move to rc.1 for now.
Do you guys know or remember the exact order in which those scripts must be loaded.
Actually, i load them in the following order:

```
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>

    <!-- angular2 bundle-->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.min.js"></script>
```

With this order the application still does not work with IE8 and Safari

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

That's the order of the beta17 quickstart project:

```
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```